# Angularjs &Angular Material : Country dependency dropdown list

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I would like to show up a dropdown list when country contains state and an input field if country does not contain states. I have added some codes here, but i don't know why they don't seem to work. When I click on the country that contains state, drop down list will work on the first time and same goes for states input field(after i refresh, not after i've clicked on the country that contains state). Countries that contain states are india and canada.

Here is my partial view code:

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl" layout="column" ng-cloak="" class="md-inline-form inputdemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">

   <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm >
                        <label>Country</label>
                        <md-select name="countryDropdown1" ng-model="candidateData.PermanentAddress.Country" ng-required="true">
                            <md-option ng-repeat="country in countrylist" value="{{country.country}}" ng-click="getCountryStates(country.id)" >
                                {{country.country}}
                            </md-option>
                        </md-select>

                    </md-input-container>

                    <md-input-container class="md-block" ng-show="stateInput">
                        <label>State</label>
                        <input required name="stateInput" ng-model="candidateData.PermanentAddress.State" ng-required="true"/>

                    </md-input-container>

                        <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm ng-show="States" >
                            <label>State</label>
                            <md-select name="stateDropdown1" ng-model="candidateData.PermanentAddress.State"ng-required="true" >
                                <md-option ng-repeat="state in states" value="{{state.state}}">
                                    {{state.state}}
                                </md-option>
                            </md-select>

                        </md-input-container>
</div>
```

Here is my angular controller: 
angular

```
  .module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
  .controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {


   $scope.getCountry = function () {
            return countrylist;
        };

        $scope.getCountryStates = function (countryId) {
            $scope.states = ($filter('filter')($scope.statelist, { countryId: countryId }));
            $scope.showStates(countryId);
        };

        $scope.States = false;
        $scope.stateInput = false;
        //$scope.showStates = function (countryId) {

        //    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.statelist.length; i++) {
        //        if ($scope.statelist[i].countryId == countryId) {
        //            $scope.States = true;
        //            return false;
        //        }

        //    }
        //    $scope.States = false;
        //    $scope.stateInput = true;
        //    return false;
        //}
        $scope.showStates = function (countryId) {

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.statelist.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.statelist[i].countryId == countryId) {
                    $scope.States = true;
                    return false;
                }
                //else {
                //    $scope.States = false;
                //    $scope.stateInput = true;
                //    return false;
                //}    
            }

            $scope.States = false;
            $scope.stateInput = true;
            return false;
        }


$scope.statelist = [{ "Id": 4, "state": "New Brunswick", "countryId": 2 },
{ "Id": 5, "state": "Manitoba", "countryId": 2 },
{ "Id": 6, "state": "Delhi", "countryId": 3 },
{ "Id": 7, "state": "Bombay", "countryId": 3 },
{ "Id": 8, "state": "Calcutta", "countryId": 3 },
{ "Id": 9, "state": "Johor", "countryId": 145 },
{ "Id": 10, "state": "Kedah", "countryId": 145 },
{ "Id": 11, "state": "Kelantan", "countryId": 145 },
{ "Id": 12, "state": "Labuan", "countryId": 145 },
{ "Id": 13, "state": "Melaka", "countryId": 145 },
{ "Id": 14, "state": "Negeri Sembilan", "countryId": 145 },
{ "Id": 15, "state": "Pahang", "countryId": 145 },
{ "Id": 16, "state": "Perak", "countryId": 145 },
{ "Id": 17, "state": "Perlis", "countryId": 145 },
{ "Id": 18, "state": "Pulau Pinang", "countryId": 145 },
{ "Id": 19, "state": "Sabah", "countryId": 145 },
{ "Id": 20, "state": "Sarawak", "countryId": 145 },
{ "Id": 21, "state": "Selangor", "countryId": 145 },
{ "Id": 22, "state": "Terengganu", "countryId": 145 },
{ "Id": 23, "state": "Wilayah Persekutuan", "countryId": 145 }]


$scope.countrylist = [
       { "id": 1, "country": "USA" },
       { "id": 2, "country": "Canada" },
       { "id": 3, "country": "India" },
       { "id": 4, "country": "Malaysia" },];

  });
```

Here is my link to the code:

http://codepen.io/zcook/pen/yOEPMa

Answer (score 0):

I simply changed your code by doing this:

```
$scope.getCountryStates = function(countryId) {
  $scope.states = ($filter('filter')($scope.statelist, function(s) {
    return s.countryId === countryId;
  }));
  $scope.candidateData.PermanentAddress.State = null;
  $scope.hasStates = $scope.states && $scope.states.length > 0;
};
```

and then I changed the html to handle the hasStates flag:

```
 <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm ng-show="hasStates" >
```

and:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" ng-show="!hasStates">
```

Probably your filter was getting all states with contains 1,2,3, or 4 in countryId (i.e countryId 145 attends USA country with id 4)

Your updated code: http://codepen.io/diegopolido/pen/MyXOEp?editors=1010

Comment: hey thanks so much! but could you help me modify it so that when i bind data from database, when state is in the country, the dropdown will automatically appear? because right now, my state is showing(and it is in statelist) but in an input field.

Comment: I didn't get your question

Answer (score 0):

HTML: use **ng-change**

```
 <md-select name="countryDropdown1" ng-model="candidateData.PermanentAddress.Country" ng-required="true">
                            <md-option ng-repeat="country in countrylist" value="{{country.country}}" ng-change="getCountryStates(country.id)" >
                                {{country.country}}
                            </md-option>
                        </md-select>
```

JS:

```
    $scope.getCountryStates = function (countryId) {
                    $scope.states = ($filter('filter')($scope.statelist, { countryId: countryId }));

                   if ($scope.states.length >0)
                     $scope.stateInput = true; 
                  else 
                    $scope.showStates(countryId);

                };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

View File:

You just need to use 3 seperate status to display appropriate result.

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" ng-show="status.countrySelected && status.stateInput">
//input
</md-input-container>

<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm ng-show="status.countrySelected && status.stateSelect">
//input
</md-input-container>
```

JS FIle

```
$scope.getCountryStates = function(countryId) {
  $scope.status.countrySelected = true;
  $scope.states = ($filter('filter')($scope.statelist, {countryId: countryId}, true));

  if($scope.states.length == 0){
       $scope.status.stateSelect = false;
       $scope.status.stateInput = true;
  }else{
       $scope.status.stateInput = false;
       $scope.status.stateSelect = true;
  }
};

$scope.status = {
  countrySelected: false,
  stateInput: false,
  stateSelect: false
};
```

Here is the full working code. http://codepen.io/next1/pen/aNKEq